# What is the best type of import to use to reduce memory usage?

Tags: node.js, typescript, memory, nestjs, ts-node

So, Hi. I recently wondered what type of import is best for my microservices on Nestjs and ts-node. With using version 20 of nodejs and version 10 of nestjs, my microservices started consuming a lot of memory. The consumption goes up to 300mb for a single pod.
I decided to try to change the way I import my dependencies when implementing my new microservice.  I changed imports only in `main.ts` and already my microservice started to consume 10mb of memory.

What I used before

```
import { NestFastifyApplication, FastifyAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
```

What I decided to try

```
import { NestFastifyApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-fastify/interfaces/nest-fastify-application.interface';
import { FastifyAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-fastify/adapters/fastify-adapter';
```

Has anyone done tests on using different types of imports? I will share my tests next week. I have enough other tasks to do right now.

Comment: Could be relevant: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wix.vscode-import-cost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done my research and tests. I came to the result that it slightly affects the amount of memory consumed. I managed to reduce memory consumption by 20-45 mb depending on the number of connected libraries. But this effect is only for those who use TS code without compiling to JS.